# From wide format to long format with MultiIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I have a data frame with two MultiIndexes (in what I understand to be "wide format") and I want to reshape it so that the second index becomes a new column (what I understand to be "long format"). Is there any easy way to do this?

This is the data frame now:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]],
             columns=['h', 'k'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4]],
             columns=['h', 'k'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
C = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6]],
             columns=['h', 'k'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'], A.columns])
B.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B'], B.columns])
C.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['C'], C.columns])
ABC = pd.concat([A, B, C], axis = 1)
```

```
   A     B     C   
   h  k  h  k  h  k
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  2  3  4  5  6
3  1  2  3  4  5  6
4  1  2  3  4  5  6
5  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
    A   B   C   new_col
1   1   3   5   h
2   1   3   5   h
3   1   3   5   h
4   1   3   5   h
5   1   3   5   h
1   2   4   6   k
2   2   4   6   k
3   2   4   6   k
4   2   4   6   k
5   2   4   6   k
```

(I hope to be able to do this directly on the data frame and not have to transform it into another object, e.g. numpy array, to avoid decreased performance).

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```py
print(
    ABC.stack(level=1)
    .reset_index(1)
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "new_col"})
    .sort_values("new_col")
)
```

Prints:

```
  new_col  A  B  C
1       h  1  3  5
2       h  1  3  5
3       h  1  3  5
4       h  1  3  5
5       h  1  3  5
1       k  2  4  6
2       k  2  4  6
3       k  2  4  6
4       k  2  4  6
5       k  2  4  6
```